# Power Series Representation of $\frac{x^2}{\sqrt[8]{x+2}}$

Tags: calculus, power-series

I know I can factor out the $x^2$ to plug back in later, but now I have $$\frac{1}{\sqrt[8]{x+2}}$$
So is the power series representation of $$\frac{1}{\sqrt[8]{x+2}} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{-\frac{1}{8}}{n}(x+1)^n$$
Please help

Comment: Yes.  It is simply the generalized binomial expansion of $(1+a)^{-1/8}$ where $a=x+1$.

Comment: @SimpleArt So my power series representation of $\frac{1}{\sqrt[8]{x+2}}$ is fine?

Comment: Yes, it is fine.  Unless you meant to center it at a different point, upon which generalized binomial expansion will still do.

Comment: @SimpleArt Thank you so much

Comment: No problemo.  Cheers!